# How can I create object of a class whose constructor is private and defined in static library as shown below

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have created one static library to be used in another applications. I have created one class in that library and make it's constructor private so will not be able to create object of that class directly from main application. To get access of that class I have created one static method, through which we can access singleton object of that class.

Now to get access of all the classes in that static library I have created one another helper class named "Helpers" through which we can get access of all the instances of static library classes.

Now problem is that I am able to create object of that class directly in my main application although I have created constructor as private in it.

Please look at following code

In Static library I have created following classes

```
//NumberHelpers.h file
//--------------------

#pragma once
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

namespace helpme
{
    class NumberHelpers
    {
    private:
        NumberHelpers();
        static NumberHelpers* _Instance;

    public:
        static NumberHelpers& Instance()
        {
            if (_Instance == nullptr)
                _Instance = new NumberHelpers();
            return *_Instance;
        }

        double RoundTo(double no, int places);
    };
}

//NumberHelpers.cpp file
//--------------------
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#include "NumberHelpers.h"
using namespace helpme;

#pragma region static variables
NumberHelpers* NumberHelpers::_Instance = NULL;
#pragma endregion

NumberHelpers::NumberHelpers() 
{
}

double NumberHelpers::RoundTo(double no, int places)
{
    //Method - 1: By using setprecision
    std::stringstream strm;
    strm << std::fixed << std::setprecision(places) << no;
    return std::stod(strm.str());
}

//Helpers.h file
//--------------
#pragma once
#include "NumberHelpers.h"
static class Helpers
{
public:
    static helpme::NumberHelpers& NumericHelper();
};

//Helpers.cpp file
//----------------
#include "pch.h"
#include "Helpers.h"

helpme::NumberHelpers& Helpers::NumericHelper()
{
    return helpme::NumberHelpers::Instance();
}
```

Now I am using this static library in my main application like shown below

```
//HelperModules.h file
//--------------------

#pragma once
#include <string>

namespace helpme
{
    extern class NumberHelpers
    {
    public:
        double RoundTo(double no, int places);
    };
}

static class Helpers
{
public:
    static helpme::NumberHelpers& NumericHelper();
};

//MfcTestAppDlg.cpp file
//-----------------------
void CMfcTestingAppDlg::OnTestClick()
{
    //I want to access NumberHelpers like this
    double rndn = Helpers::NumericHelper().RoundTo(5.2483435643232, 2);

    //But I am also able to create object of NumberHelpers here whose constructor in private
    helpme::NumberHelpers nh;
    double testval = nh.RoundTo(4.2343, 2);
}
```

Comment: I've no idea what you are trying to do here. I would just delete the 'helper' classes `Helpers` and `NumberHelpers`. In what way to you think these classes are helping? To me it seems they are just adding needless complexity.

Comment: Using singletons should usually not be your first choice (they have their uses but only limited use cases). In most scenarios you're better of with dependeny injection

Comment: THis doesn't look like C++ to me. Classes in C++ cannot be extern or static.

Comment: Also AFAIK `static class X { ... };` and `extern class X { ... };` are not legal C++. `static` and `extern` are applied to variables and functions, but not classes.

Comment: Also you have repeated the definition of `Helpers` for some reason, not illegal, but definitely not good practise.

Comment: Basically the code is a mess, you should start again, and this time try to resist the temptation to have three classes where only one is needed.

Comment: But my main question is how I am able to create object of NumberHelper in my main class as it's constructor is declared private?

Comment: Honestly both your code and design are flawed. Derive your class from a pure abstract baseclass (interface) Remove most of your code, make your constructor public. Create instances where needed, e.g. in main (ensure they live long enough) and pass the interface by reference to code that needs access to instances (dependency injection). That way you will also end up with unit testable code. Globals/singletons are a form of reference semantics that create implicit dependencies between software components and those are going to bit when your project grows.

Comment: You have ODR violation by defining class `helpme::NumberHelpers` differently in 2 different TUs. your programs is ill-formed NDR.

Comment: @dipatel You have repeated the definition of `helpme::NumberHelpers` with different definitions each time. That makes your code illegal, so it is not surprising that the compiler is confused about that class.

Comment: @dipatel You seem to think that because you have defined one version of `helpme::NumberHelpers` as `extern` that somehow the compiler should be connecting the two versions of the class. That is a misunderstanding of how C++ works. If you have two definitions of the same class they must be Identical. And, of course, the usual way to achieve this is to put the class definition in a header file and include the header file wherever you need it,

Comment: @dipatel It looks like you are trying to hide the implementation of your class from the code that uses the class. There are ways to do this (look up PIMPL idiom for example) but the way you are trying does not work, it is not legal C++.

Comment: *"Now I am using this static library in my main application like shown below"* -- When I tired to use this code, my compiler complained *"error: a storage class can only be specified for objects and functions"* (twice). I don't see how you could use the library as in this code.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2022 community edition and able to run code and call functions in both ways as shown but "second call should not work as it's constructor is private."

Comment: @dipatel Just because a compiler accepts code and even runs code does not mean the code is legal. As was mentioned above the error that you have made (same class but two different definitions) is a NDR error, NDR stands for *no diagnostic required*. You have written illegal code but for this particular error the compiler is not required to tell you that.

Comment: I advise trimming down your code even more to make it easier to focus on what's important. Removing unneeded headers is a great way to cut down on clutter. So is making function stubs and inlining their definitions (provided, of course, that doing so does not remove what you are asking about). For example, `class NumberHelpers {
private:
NumberHelpers() = default;` removes the need to define the constructor in `NumberHelpers.cpp`. Similarly, you could stub out `double RoundTo(double no, int places) { return no; /*placeholder*/ }` or even `double fun() { return 12.0; }`.

Comment: @dipatel *"second call should not work as it's constructor is private."* -- There is no private constructor in the code you've shown for your main application.

Comment: I have defined private constructor in static library class. In main application I have just declared it as extern to be used from static library and haven't declared constructor here. If that extern declaration is different from static library class it should give error but I am able to create an object and call function from static library class. How it's possible?

Comment: @dipatel I don't know how many times I can say the same thing. Your code has an error (for the reason already explained) but for this error **NO DIAGNOSTIC IS REQUIRED**. For this kind of error the compiler does not have to tell you anything.

Comment: @dipatel You said 'It should give an error'. That is not true, because **NO DIAGNOSTIC IS REQUIRED**. This is the rules of C++, for the error you made the compiler is not required to give an error message. Of course the answer is not to try to write code like this in the first place.

Comment: @dipatel C++ is the language it is, you cannot say that is should do this or that, you cannot say that it should be a different language. Ultimately if you do not like the way C++ is, then you choose a different language.

Comment: In C++, access control is meant to help programmers do the right thing, to use classes the way they were designed to be used. It's not a security mechanism - it doesn't prevent a programmer from intentionally abusing the language and misusing the class. Like for example providing two different definitions for the same class in two translation units, in violation of the One Definition Rule.

Comment: If the constructor is `private`, that's a pretty big hint that you are not supposed to instantiate that object (or at least call a factory function).

Comment: @dipatel *"In main application I have just declared it as extern to be used from static library and haven't declared constructor here."* -- Right. It is when compiling the main application when the issue arises. Things in other translation units (such as your static library) have no bearing on compiling your main application. Translation units are compiled independent of each other. There is no private constructor **in your main application**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is infringing the **[one definition rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)** (ODR): your code does in reality redefine the class `NumberHelpers` in another compilation unit with a version that has a default constructor.  As a consequence, your program has undefined behaviour.

The reason is that extern does not what you think.  As GCC explains extern is added in front of a class definition:

> error: a storage class can only be specified for objects and functions

A better practice would be to apply the [**C++ core guidelines**](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-source) recommendation to [use headers for all declaration used in multiple source files](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rs-declaration-header).  A practical way to this would be to include in `HelperModules.h` the `NumberHelpers.h` header.